# How to combine stock prices downloaded on different days with adjustments aligned

Tags: python, stock, yfinance

I download adjusted intraday stock prices from either yahoo or some other sources. I request auto adjusted prices so that the splits and dividents are already backed into the price. Since the intraday prices typically have available dates limited to a very short period of time, I want to regularly download them and append to my previous downloads to accumulate the data in my local cache. However, if I download the same stock before and after a split, the adjusted prices will be very different.

Is there a good python solution to re-adjust the older downloads so that their adjusted prices align with the latest download? Ideally an existing library that does this for me. Or a function could work too.

UPDATE:
I found out how Yahoo finance adjusts its prices from this link.

https://help.yahoo.com/kb/adjusted-close-sln28256.html

Basically both split and divident are applied as multipliers. In that case, does it make sense to derive the multiplier change from the closing price of the previous download day vs today's version of its closing price? For example, say I last downloaded on D0 and the closing price for that day was P0. Today I downloaded the closing price for D0 again and it's now P0_1. This implies all intraday prices I downloaded on D0 for all days before D0 should be multiplied by the ratio of P0_1/P0 before I merge/concat it with intraday prices I download today. Can someone who has more experience confirm my logic is correct?

---

I thought about possibly trying to back out the splits and dividents from the differences in the downloaded adjusted prices. However, tbh, I'm not very sure how about the 2 events affect the adjustment calculation and don't want to continue based on wrong assumptions. Is the divident adjustment effectively a multiplier? Or is it an offset?